# How can I add boost threads to a vector

Tags: c++, boost

I have something like this that is incorect:

```
vector<boost::thread> vec;
for(int agent = 1; agent <= numAgents; ++agent)
{
    boost::thread agentThread(sellTickets, agent, numTickets/numAgents);
    vec.push_back(agentThread);
}
```

Maybe i should add pointers to boost::thread in the vector, but then I don't know how to add dynamic allocated threads, how should I do to make this work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- You must have a compiler with move-semantics supported in order to make your code work,
- or use `vector<shared_ptr<boost::thread>>` with code like:

  ```
  vec.push_back(make_shared<boost::thread>(sellTickets, agent, numTickets/numAgents));
  ```
- or use `boost::thread_group`.

Comment: thank you, thread_groups worked for me, didnt know about them, i learned something new :)

Comment: @nabulke - It doesn't work, because you cannot copy a thread. Would that make it two threads? It will work better in C++0x where you can move objects instead of copying them.