# std::vector of objects with a boost::thread encapsulated insde

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

How do I create a std::vector of objects, and each object has a boost::thread encapsulated inside.

```
class INSTRUMENT {
public:
    INSTRUMENT() : m_thread(new boost::thread(&INSTRUMENT::Start, this)) {  
        x = "abc";
    } 
    ~INSTRUMENT() {}
    void Start();
public:
    std::string x;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> m_thread;
};

void INSTRUMENT::Start() {
    try {
        while (1) {
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            std::cout << "here " << x << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::thread_interrupted &thread_e) {
        std::cout << "exit " << x << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
    }
}

std::vector<INSTRUMENT> m_inst_vector;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m_inst_vector.push_back(INSTRUMENT());
}
```

The code compiles fine, but the output is just some garbage, not "abc" as expected. In debug, I notice that ~INSTRUMENT() is called every time when .push_back() is called.

I tried not to use boost::group_thread, because of the limitation on the current design. Just wondering whether it is possible to have a std::vector of objects with a thread inside, or any suggestion to a similar design would be very helpful.

I find a similar thread on SO. It mentioned about move-semantics supported in compiler, but didn't explain what it is. 
[How can I add boost threads to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416800/how-can-i-add-boost-threads-to-a-vector)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

Firstly, the thread starts running immediately the `boost::thread` object is constructed, so you need to ensure that any data it accesses is initialized beforehand --- i.e. initialize `x` in the member initialization list prior to constructing the thread.

Secondly, the thread uses the `this` pointer of the `INSTRUMENT` object, so your object is tied to a specific address. `std::vector` **copies** values around: when you call `push_back` then it copies the object into the vector, and adding additional elements may copy the others around if a new memory block has to be allocated to make room. This is the cause of the destructor calls you see: the temporary is constructed, `push_back` copies it to the vector, and then the temporary is destructed.

To fix this, you need to ensure that once constructed your `INSTRUMENT` objects cannot be moved or copied, as copies have the wrong semantics. Do this by making your copy constructor and assignment operator private and unimplemented (or marking them deleted if you have a recent compiler that supports this new C++11 construct), or deriving from `boost::noncopyable`. Having done this then you no longer need a `shared_ptr` for the thread, as it cannot be shared, so you can just construct it directly.

If `INSTRUMENT` is not copyable, you can't store it directly in a vector, so use something like `boost::shared_ptr<INSTRUMENT>` in the vector. This will allow the vector to freely copy and reshuffle its elements, without affecting the address of the `INSTRUMENT` object, and ensuring that it is correctly destroyed at the end.

```
class INSTRUMENT: boost::noncopyable {
public:
    INSTRUMENT() : x("abc"),m_thread(&INSTRUMENT::Start, this) {  
    } 
    ~INSTRUMENT() {}
    void Start();
public:
    std::string x;
    boost::thread m_thread;
};

void INSTRUMENT::Start() {
    try {
        while (1) {
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            std::cout << "here " << x << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::thread_interrupted &thread_e) {
        std::cout << "exit " << x << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
    }
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<INSTRUMENT> > m_inst_vector;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m_inst_vector.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<INSTRUMENT>(new INSTRUMENT));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Antony. Your code is exactly what I have been looking for and it works 100%.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: You have a race condition in your code. The thread starts before `x` gets initialized.

You should change the vector to `vector<boost::shared_ptr<INSTRUMENT> >`, and remove the `boost::shared_ptr` from inside `INSTRUMENT`.

```
class INSTRUMENT {
public:
    INSTRUMENT() {  
        x = "abc";
        m_thread = boost::thread(&INSTRUMENT::Start, this) 
    } 
    ~INSTRUMENT() {}
    void Start();
public:
    std::string x;
    boost::thread m_thread;
};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    m_inst_vector.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<INSTRUMENT>(new INSTRUMENT()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I still have the same problem, ~INSTRUMENT() gets called after .push_back() gets called. m_inst_vector.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Test>(new Test()));