# Initialize vector of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm on a GCC (4.6.3) compiler on Ubuntu 12.04. I try to initialize a vector of boost::thread (with boost ver: 1.54.0), but I got a weird bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::thread> list_threads(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And that's my error message:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:84: error: passing 'const
>   boost::thread' as 'this' argument of 'boost::thread::operator
>   boost::detail::thread_move_t()' discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

How to solve this problem ? I hope i'm not the only one with that :p

For information, this code compiles on mcsv2010.

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't use MS VC2010 as a standard here... MS allows things that are very much not good behavior although you can [make it better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w455da8a.aspx) at the cost of breaking your compilation.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416800/how-can-i-add-boost-threads-to-a-vector

Comment: ok now i use thread_group, and it works thank you !!